# Padding in d3.scaleBand

Tags: d3.js

Need some help to understand use of padding function's parameter in calculating the total empty space. Here is my code

The empty space as per code is 48.72 Formula = (xScale.step()-xScale.bandwidth())*(data.length+1)

Should it not be equal to [Range * padding] i.e. (400*.1) = 40
How can we use (padding of 0.1) to determine the total empty space??

```
let data=["a","b","c","d"]
var xScale = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d=>d))
            .range([0, 400])
            .padding(.1)
let all_bars_width=xScale.bandwidth() * data.length
let emptyspace=(xScale.step()-xScale.bandwidth())*(data.length+1)
let total_space=all_bars_width + emptyspace
console.log(all_bars_width)//returns 351.22
console.log(emptyspace) //returns 48.78
console.log(total_space)//returns 400 ..a perfect match
```